# How to find dates from multiple categories by conditions

Tags: sql, presto

I need to find the data in different categories: Breakground, Energization and PR based on conditions. The first two categories are fine. The data is one to one mapping. The problem is PR category. There are several dates in this category. I need to find the min(MilestoneDate) in this category but the min(MilesotoneDate) must be greater than today and closest to today.

```
Following are table data:

Site   Building       MilestoneID   MilestoneType  MilestoneDate
 AGE     building1     MIC.MS.1000    Breakground    1/1/18
 AGE     building1     MIC.ACT.1000   Energization   2/3/19
 AGE     building1     PTM.B1.1130    PR             2/5/19
 AGE     building1     PTM.B1.1140    PR             3/4/20
 AGE     building1     PTM.B1.1150    PR             12/25/20
 AGE     building1     PTM.B1.1160    PR             5/25/22
 AGE     building2     MIC.MS.1000    Breakground    2/2/19
 AGE     building2     MIC.ACT.1000   Energization   12/5/19
 AGE     building2     PTM.B2.1130    PR             3/5/20
 AGE     building2      PTM.B2.1140   PR             8/10/20
 AGE     building2      PTM.B2.1150   PR             3/4/21
 AGE     building2      PTM.B2.1160   PR             5/4/22
 OCA     building1     MIC.MS.1000    Breakground    4/2/19
 OCA     building1     MIC.ACT.1000   Energization   5/4/20  
 OCA     building1      PTM.B1.1130   PR             6/8/21
 OCA     building1     PTM.B1.1140    PR             12/2/21
 OCA     building1     PTM.B1.1150    PR             3/5/22
 OCA     building1     PTM.B1.1160    PR             12/30/22
```

WITH managementview AS 
( 
          SELECT    * 
          FROM      management_view_nancy m 
          LEFT JOIN 
                    ( 
                           SELECT * 
                           FROM   ( 
                                         SELECT projectobjectid, 
                                                id         AS activity_id, 
                                                finishdate AS milestonedate, 
                                                NAME       AS milestone 
                                         FROM   activity 
                                         WHERE  ds = 
                                                ( 
                                                       SELECT Max(ds) 
                                                       FROM   activity) 
                                         UNION ALL 
                                         SELECT   projectobjectid, 
                                                  id              AS activity_id, 
                                                  Min(finishdate) AS finishdate, 
                                                  NAME 
                                         FROM     activity 
                                         WHERE    id IN ('LRP-RVA-B3-FS1000', 
                                                         'LRP-RVA-B3-PR1000', 
                                                         'LRP-RVA-B3-PR1500') 
                                         AND      projectobjectid = 4908 
                                         GROUP BY projectobjectid, 
                                                  id, 
                                                  NAME) ) p 
          ON        try_cast(m.objectid as DOUBLE) = p.projectobjection 
          AND       m.id = p.activity_id ) , pr AS 
( 
         SELECT   *, 
                  row_number() OVER (partition BY site, building, milestonetype ORDER BY try(cast(substr(milestonedate, 1, 10) AS date))) rn
         FROM     managementview 
         WHERE    try(cast(substr(milestonedate, 1, 10) AS date)) >= CURRENT_DATE 
         AND      trim(milestonetype) = 'PR') 
SELECT site, 
       building, 
       id, 
       milestonetype, 
       milestone, 
       milestonedate 
FROM   managementview 
WHERE  milestonetype IN ('Breakground', 
                         'Energization') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT site, 
       building, 
       id, 
       milestonetype, 
       milestone, 
       milestonedate 
FROM   pr 
WHERE  rn = 1

The query works fine, but it didn't get the result I want. I need the min(MilestoneDate) in PR category, and the min(MilestoneDate) should be greater than today but closest to today. This query still gives me multiple MilestoneDate in PR category. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a CTE to bring in the PR data points you want to retain:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Site, Building ORDER BY MilestoneDate) rn
    FROM managementview
    WHERE MilestoneDate >= CURRENT_DATE AND milestonetype = 'PR'
)

SELECT site, building, id, milestonetype, milestone, milestonedate
FROM managementview
WHERE milestonetype IN ('Breakground', 'Energization')
UNION ALL
SELECT site, building, id, milestonetype, milestone, milestonedate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If your version of Presto does not support CTE, then try inlining it:

```
SELECT site, building, id, milestonetype, milestone, milestonedate
FROM managementview
WHERE milestonetype IN ('Breakground', 'Energization')
UNION ALL
SELECT site, building, id, milestonetype, milestone, milestonedate
FROM
(
    SELECT m.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Site, Building ORDER BY MilestoneDate) rn
    FROM managementview m
    WHERE MilestoneDate >= CURRENT_DATE AND milestonetype = 'PR'
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the help. Your solution is great.  I'm trying to integrate your solution with mine. But I've got this error message: Generic_internal_error) internal error. Not sure which part is wrong in the query.With ManagementView as (

Comment: @Nancy What happens if you just run `SELECT * FROM cte` ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I posted my modified query. I integrated yours in my query, but there is error message. It says 'internal error'.  Sorry the above code is very messy.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I can't see a more precise error message, I can't even guess at what might be wrong with my answer.

Comment: With ManagementView as (
) this is my first CTE. It works!

Comment: I think your logic solution is correct. I used two CTE here. not sure if it is correct or not.  I integrated your solution into my query, I've got the error message: 'internal error'.

Comment: where is the 'green checkmark' to the left? I didn't see it on the left.